# How to run Control Add-ins method from another Page in Dynamics NAV?

Tags: nav, microsoft-dynamics

I have developed a .net Control Add-in(DropBoxAddIn) and applied that control on field property of Dynamics NAV page(Drop Box). Then I have included Drop Box page in parts of another page(Customer Card).

Drop Box Page has a method SetDocReference(), and I am trying to call that method from Customer Page C/AL method as below.
CurrPage."".PAGE.SetDocReference('CUSTOMER',"No.",0);
It's showing an exception like "The control add-in on control DropBoxAddIn on page Drop box has not been instantiated. Page View - Customer card must close."

If I comment the above piece of code and run the customer card page, then it's working and the control add-in displayed on the page and their functionalities are working fine.

Please help me to get it fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Because of the Life Cycle of Dynamics NAV Pages your Control Add-In is not loaded, when you call `SetDocReference`. I suggest you implement the `ControlAddInReady` Event ([Adding a ControlAddInReady event to custom controls](http://vjeko.com/adding-a-controladdinready-event-to-custom-controls/)). You can store your Information in Global Variable(s) in the Page *Drop Box* as long as the control is not ready and if `ControlAddInReady` gets call transfer the information. After that `SetDocReference()` would work directly.